# Postfix check ip and dns for junk mail

Tags: linux, postfix, spam

These days I am receiving emails that contain links to temporary cloud that will surely contain malware. The only thing I notice strange to be in the header of the email is this:
Received: from mx.y.com (mx.y.com [1.2.3.4]) ------- mx.y.com does not have the url ip 1.2.3.4 but another one. How can I tell Postfix check and discard? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, `Received: from` headers are first to forge by spammers. You might have more than one `Received: from` headers in the received messages. At least one of them should contain correct `Received: from hostname(hostname[ip address])`.

What you probably want is rejecting forged messages. Aside from setting up `SpamAssassin` to mark such messages as spam, quickest and easiest way to get rid of *most* of the spam messages (or, at least *large number of them*) is to reject hosts that are known to forge addresses and that do it repeatedly by using public [DNSBL's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNSBL).

When speaking of Postfix, you do that by editing `main.cf` and modifying `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` in such manner:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
   reject_unauth_pipelining,
   reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
   reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
   permit_mynetworks,
   reject_unauth_destination,
   reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org, #1, zen.spamhaus
   reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net,   #2, smapcop
   permit
```

(Beware, `reject_unauth_destination`, is **critically important** since it tells Postfix not to accept messages with recipients at domains that are not hosted locally. Without this line, your server would be an open relay.)